# Editable Grid view update is not working

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to update gridview data using editable gridview but i am unable to get the edit template values in code behind.Here is the code to update grid view

```
protected void mGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string name="";
        string email="";
        string password="";
        string phone="";
        string address="";
        string id="";
        try
        {
        password = ((TextBox)mGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMPass")).Text;
        phone = ((TextBox)mGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMphone")).Text;
        address = ((TextBox)mGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMaddress")).Text;

        name = ((Label)mGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblMname")).Text;
        email = ((Label)mGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblMemail")).Text;

        id = getUID(email, name);

        com.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET userPass=@pass,userPh=@ph,userAdd=@add WHERE userID=@id and userType='Manager'";
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph", phone);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", address);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id );
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }

        mGrid.EditIndex = -1;
        loadGrid();
        Response.Write(name + email + password + phone + address+"");
    }

private void loadGrid()
    {
        com.CommandText = "select * from Users where userType='Manager'";
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
            mGrid.DataSource = r;
            mGrid.DataBind();
            r.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Response.Write(exp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

in Response.Write(---) i am getting the old values instead of the values i changed inside the grid

here is my gridview

```
<div class="col-md-9 table-responsive" style="margin-    top:10%;float:right;margin-right:6%;font-family:Calibri;font-size:13px;">
     <asp:GridView ID="mGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowUpdating="mGrid_RowUpdating"
         CssClass="table  table-striped" onrowediting="EditCustomer" GridLines="None"
          OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" >
         <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate >
                     <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/manager.png" Width="30" Height="30" runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                 <ItemTemplate >
                     <asp:Label ID="lblMname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userName")%>' ></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userName")%>' ></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblMemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userEmail")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userEmail")%>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblMPass" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userPass")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMPass" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userPass")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblMphone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userPh")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMphone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userPh")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblMaddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userAdd")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userAdd")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("userID")%>' 
                        OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" 
                        Text = "Delete" OnClick="lnkRemove_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" />
         </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

if someone can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the initial loading of the GridView values inside a IsPostBack check, otherwise the default values will be loaded and will overwrite the submitted ones.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: i solved this error by Disabling the view state of grid view but i will try this one too :) thanks :)